# Custom Widget Not Appearing

Tags: magento2

I created a module with a Custom Widget. When logging into the admin, going to `content->widgets`, creating an instance, and setting that instance to appear on the homepage, the widget appears as expected.

I have removed this instance and am now trying to create the widget by going to `content->pages`, editing the `homepage -> content` section, and selecting `insert widget`. I created a new instance of the widget and added some additional `text` into the `homepage -> content` section.

When I load the homepage the widget does not appear, though the rest of the `text` does appear.

The block for the widget is being called ( I tested this with a `var_dump` and `exit`).

The template is not being rendered however.

Here is my Block:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Slider\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;

class Slider extends Template
{
    protected $_template = "Yamazaki_Slider::widget/slider.phtml";

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_imageHelper;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory)
    {
        $this->_imageHelper = $context->getImageHelper();
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve featured products collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        return $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured','1');
    }
}
```

and my Template:

```
<?php $imageBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct'); ?>

<?php foreach($this->getProducts() as $product): ?>
    <?php $productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($product, 'product_page_image_large'); ?>
    <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

## Update

If I "Hide the Editor" inside `content->pages->edit->content` I see:

```
<p>{{widget type="MyNamespace\Slider\Block\Widget\Slider"}}</p>`
```

If I replace this with

```
{{block class="MyNamespace\Slider\Block\Widget\Slider" template="widget/slider.phtml"}}
```

The Content appears as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get the Block to Render

I had to add `implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface` to  `MyNamespace\Slider\Block\Widget\Slider`.

I'm not sure why this rendered, prior to adding the `implements`, using the first approach and not the second.

Magento is seriously lacking documentation!

Answer (score 0):

please check code for get image.

```
$imagewidth=200;
$imageheight=200;
$imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize($imagewidth, $imageheight)->getUrl();
   echo $image_url;
```

After do, please flush cache

Comment: is that work for you?

Comment: This is not the problem, the images are appearing just fine when the widget is added through `content->widgets`.

Comment: Forget about the images entirely. If I change the template to be `<?php echo 'working?'; exit; ?>` It will show `working?` in approach 1 and not approach 2

Comment: enable hint path and check which phtml is called

Comment: Also, I noticed I must have removed my widget.xml file at somepoint. I had 2 parameters initially. I recreated the xml file without any parameters though the 2 initial parameters still appear when creating the widget. Not sure if this has anything to do with it

Comment: What is hint path? I don't believe any phtml file is being called

Comment: Sorry very new to Magento here :) and finding Documentation to be very sparse

Comment: please go that page and remove it and add again.
in setting >> develper enable hint path in frontend site so you can check which template file called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68840/discussion-between-shawn-northrop-and-sunil-patel).